# GL-iNET, what does it mean when the LED flashes red?

Tags: troubleshooting, diagnostics, routers

I'm working with a GL-iNET router, and before it stopped working, it was running their tor firmware from 2/2/2015 (the file doesn't have a version number).

At some point it broke and now when it turns on, the LED flashes red.  I couldn't find a manual for the device, and I'm not that familiar with Open-WRT/DD-WRT (the tor firmware is based on one of these).  Would this be something to consult their documentation about?

What does a flashing red LED mean?  After it boots up, it flashes ~4/sec green for ~3 -4 seconds, then it flashes red ~4/sec.  Periodically, the LED will stay red for a little while longer and then it will resume its normally 4/sec flash rate.

The wifi is broadcasting (I can see the SSIDs), and I can access the web UI via the LAN port (and presumably the non-tor wifi).  I've reset the device before, but I'd like to know what's going on.

Comment: Seems like a hardware/firmware issue, not a Tor issue. Might need to contact the manufacturer for support. Solid lights on hardware often means that it's bricked in a static state that would require you to reset it back to factory defaults and/or reflash the firmware... but I have no idea

Comment: This question is off-topic and not about tor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, it turns out that the LEDs are configurable in OpenWRT, and on this device they were configured to blink red by default.  I didn't quite get all the settings and what they meant, but I found the docs by searching for the current values.

[This page](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/system) goes over the capabilities of the LED and what they mean (scroll down to WiFi activity).

The default is to blink the LED red on phy0tpt, so I fiddled with the settings to get the router to do what I wanted.  It seems that the LED settings will take effect without a reboot, but I had to do a power cycle to get them to fully take.  Before the power cycle, i was getting multi-colored flashes.  Afterwards, solid green like I wanted.

Now that I have the docs and know what it means, I may play around with it.